# How to filter a List of strings and split them and return an Array in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-stream

I have to filter strings from a list containing lines shown below.

```
"15:09:00 SOME TEXT SOME TEXT 088"
"15:09 SOME TEXT 1546 AMOUNT"
"15:09:06 SOME TEXT 1546 AMOUNT"
"13:03:00 SOME TEXT TEXT TEXT 00"
```

I want to get elements that start with `15:09` and then split the line by white space. The `split()` method returns an array.

How to collect this to an array using streams?

I've tried the code below. I don't understand how to collect the data to array, that's why here method `collect()` returns a list.

```
String [] parts = myList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.startsWith("19:01 "))
    .map(l -> l.split("\\s+"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What have you done so far? What isn't working properly? Try to produce a [mre]

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Updated the question, i am looking for arrays of splitted Strings.

Comment: Why do you need an array? In most settings you are better of with a List, which you already managed to create!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> split returns an array

You need to apply [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) in order to produce a stream of `Strings` from a stream of `Strings[]`.

And in order to collect the stream data into an array, you need to apply [`toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)), which expects a function that produces an array of the desired type, as terminal operation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = 
        List.of("15:09:00 SOME TEXT SOME TEXT 088",
                "15:09 SOME TEXT 1546 AMOUNT",
                "15:09:06 SOME TEXT 1546 AMOUNT",
                "13:03:00 SOME TEXT TEXT TEXT 00");
    
    String[] parts = getParts(myList, "15:09:06", "\\s+");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}

public static String[] getParts(List<String> source, String prefix, String delimiter) {
    return source.stream()
        .filter(str -> str.startsWith(prefix)) // Stream<String>
        .map(str -> str.split(delimiter))      // Stream<String[]>
        .flatMap(Stream::of)                   // Stream<String>
        .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

**Output**

```
[15:09:06, SOME, TEXT, 1546, AMOUNT]
```

Comment: Thank you but why flatMap and toArray both?

Comment: @nilFi `flatMap()` will transform a `Stream<String[]>` into a `Stream<String>`, so that when you apply `toArray()` you'll get a `String[]` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatMap and split together.

```
String [] parts = myList.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.startsWith("19:01 "))
    .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split("\\s+")))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```